# style width menu of react-native-paper

Tags: react-native, flexbox, react-native-paper

I have a menu with a anchor to a button.

I would like to style width of menu such as button.

I have try with `style=width:100%` but doesn't works. If I change the dimension in pixel, it change.

How I can style with flex mode (for dynamic width).

This is an example:
https://snack.expo.io/@temuccio/menu

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution: use List.Item instead of Menu.Item

I tried solution mentioned in https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/issues/2314#issuecomment-716496115

but some how even if the width of Menu.Item becomes 100% ,some part of Menu.Item at right becomes not clickable
so only solution that worked for me was to replace Menu.Item with List.Item

This is an example:https://snack.expo.io/@gautami123/menu

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use `flex: 1` to style this, you should pass this as the style prop: `style={{ flex: 1 }}`.

Comment: I use this. If you view the example at 20th row there is `style={{flex:8}}`. I have try to change the number of flex but the width are fixed.